# How to speed up my Raspberry pi

Tags: boot, processor-speed

I'm planning to do **Auto start Chromium-Browser in kiosk mode.**
But it takes 45 sec (from powerup raspberry) to totally load the particular link.

is there any way to decrease the time..?

Comment: `it takes 45 sec to totally load the particular link` network issue, or do you mean from power on to display link?

Comment: No network is working good. Here im mention from power up the raspberry pi

Comment: well, the pi takes time to boot up - I've knocked off 9 seconds by adding `boot_delay=0`
`boot_delay_ms=0`
`disable_splash=1`
`avoid_safe_mode=1` to config.txt ... not sure if the last two actually make a difference, I just know I added those 4 lines together one day
`

Comment: yes, it's working successfully.

Comment: what were the results?

Comment: there will be 6 sec knocked off by adding those commands.

Comment: Take a look at the output from ```systemd-analyze blame``` command.